# Maven profile activation - how to define several conditions for activations

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Maven profile `<activation>` block used to be a list of `OR` statements until v3.2.2. However, once the http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4565 was resolved it became a list of `AND` statements e.g.:

```
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <os>
               <name>linux</name>
            </os>
            <property>
                <name>release</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
         </activation>
```

The following profile would be activated when the OS is linux **AND** the `release` property is set to `true`. The question is - how would it be possible to configure **OR** logic i.e. either OS is linux
**OR** `release` property is set to `true` for maven v3.2.2 and above ?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is that you cannot do it... Well not unless you copy-paste the profile, one with each of the 2 possible activations. Or use XML entities http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997522/hibernate-entity

Comment: @Tunaki, thank you for your quick response. This is actually smth. I was afraid of.

Comment: @Tunaki Post your answer as answer and get the credit for.

Comment: @IlyaBuziuk Unfortunately, the boolean logic of activation was not properly documented and communicated to the users. At some point it has been corrected but broke some code.

Comment: @Michael-O that is really pity. Do you happen to know if there is an issue for maven team coupled with creating OR logic ?

Comment: @IlyaBuziuk there are several issues worth reading: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3328, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4516, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4565 as well as those linked in the issues itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now it is not possible to configure `OR`logic for maven profile activation (unless to copy-paste the profile, one with each of the 2 possible ways of activation):

Related JIRA issues:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3328
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4516
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4565

> Thanks to the **@Tunaki** and **@Michael-O** for their comments to the
>   original question - more details can be found there